# Elastic Search - Even distribution on a map

Tags: google-maps, elasticsearch

I'm using Elastic Search 2. I have a big database of locations, all of them have a `gps` attribute, which is a `geopoint`. 
My frontend application displays a google maps component with the results, filtered by my query, let's say `pizza`. The problem is that the dataset grew a lot, and the client wants even results on the map.

So if I search for a specific query in New York, i would like to have results all over New York, but i'm currently receiving 400 results only in one populous area of Manhattan.

My naive approach was to just filter by distance

```
{  
   "size":400,
   "query":{  
      "bool":{  
         "must":{  
            "match_all":{  

            }
         },
         "filter":{  
            "geo_distance":{  
               "distance":"200km",
               "gps":[  
                  -73.98502023369585,
                  40.76195656809083
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

This doesn't guarantee that the results will be spread across the map.
How can I do it?

I've tried using [Geo-Distance Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/geo-distance-agg.html) for this

```
{  
   "size":400,
   "query":{  
      "bool":{  
         "must":{  
            "match_all":{  

            }
         },
         "filter":{  
            "geo_distance":{  
               "distance":"200km",
               "gps":[  
                  -73.98502023369585,
                  40.76195656809083
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "aggs":{  
      "per_ring":{  
         "geo_distance":{  
            "field":"gps",
            "unit":"km",
            "origin":[  
               -73.98502023369585,
               40.76195656809083
            ],
            "ranges":[  
               {  
                  "from":0,
                  "to":100
               },
               {  
                  "from":100,
                  "to":200
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

But i just receive a results list + the amount of elements that belong to the buckets.  The results list is not guaranteed to be spread.

```
"aggregations": {
    "per_ring": {
        "buckets": [
            {
                "key": "*-100.0",
                "from": 0,
                "from_as_string": "0.0",
                "to": 100,
                "to_as_string": "100.0",
                "doc_count": 33821
            },
            {
                "key": "100.0-200.0",
                "from": 100,
                "from_as_string": "100.0",
                "to": 200,
                "to_as_string": "200.0",
                "doc_count": 6213
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I would like to grab half of the results from one bucket, half from the other bucket.

I've also attempted to use [Geohash Grid Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/geohash-grid-agg.html), but that also doesn't give me samples of results for every bucket, just provides the areas.

So how do I get a spaced distribution of results spread across my map with one elastic search query?

Thanks!

Comment: Does your doc count far exceed the 400 limit you're providing? I'm wondering if index order has something to do with your spread, since as far as I can tell you're not doing scoring based on distance, just an unscored filter.

Comment: Yeah, i have around half a million objects. Should i do scoring based on distance?

Comment: I'm thinking you could do something like that. Perhaps performing a query that in the range of 0-100, then another query in the range of 101-200, etc. and limit the sizes to something that fits your approximate goal for distribution, perhaps mapping multiple result sets? I would have concerns over  misrepresentation of the distribution using this approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think introducing some randomness may give you the desired result. I am assuming you're seeing the same distribution because of index ordering (you're not scoring based on distance, and you're taking the first 400 so you are most likely seeing the same result set).

```
{
  "size": 400,
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match_all": {}
            }
          ],
          "filter": {
            "geo_distance": {
              "distance": "200km",
              "gps": [
                -73.98502023369585,
                40.76195656809083
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "random_score": {}
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

[Random score in elastic](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/random-scoring.html)

Comment: that's a great idea! it solved my problem. Thank you very much!